# Rest API to know whether Foreign Principle (IAM) is assigned to a Tenant or Subscription in Azure

Tags: azure

Rest API to know whether Foreign Principle (IAM) is assigned to a Tenant or Subscription in Azure

[image]

Comment: Could my reply solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the `Foreign principal` was added to your subscription, you could not do that via only one REST API.

The [`Role Assignments - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/list) will list all the role assignments in your subscription, but it just returns them as Ids, the `Foreign principal` is a group named `Foreign Principal for 'CSPPartnerName' in role 'TenantAdmins' (CSPCustomer Directory)`, it is not visible in your Azure AD in the portal, so it is difficult to get the `ObjectId` of the group to know which one is the `Foreign principal`.

[image]

Actually, to check if the Foreign principal was added, the easiest way is to use azure powershell [`Get-AzRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.Resources/Get-azRoleAssignment?view=azps-3.1.0) .

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like 'Foreign*'}
```

[image]

If you just want to use REST APIs, you could use the tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to catch the request of the command. You will find it call the [`Role Assignments - List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/authorization/roleassignments/list) and [`getObjectsByObjectIds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getObjectsByObjectIds).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you want to directly call the REST API from code, use the Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments REST API.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments?api-version=2018-01-01-previe
```